# DISTINCT result of ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG in BigQuery

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery, aggregate-functions

I need to compute distinct set of items from the aggregated arrays. I cannot use the array_concat as suggested in similar threads, as I don't know how many arrays I'll be concatenating.
I've tried using the following, but it's not allowed in BigQuery:

```
select ARRAY(select DISTINCT(flattened_subjects) from UNNEST(ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(subjects))) flattened_subjects as subjects, ... 
from ...
```

What works is having a nested select but I find it too cluttered:

```
select 
  (select ARRAY(select DISTINCT(subject) from unnest(flattened_subjects) subject) as subjects
   ...
from
   select ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(subjects) flattened_subjects, ... from ...
```

Any ideas how to do it in a simple way? All I need is something like that:

```
select ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(DISTINCT subjects) as subjects, ... from ...
```

Comment: please provide some sample data!

Comment: As @MikhailBerlyant points out, some sample data would help ! Otherwise, your syntax seems very close to what BQ expects: have a look at the *filtering arrays* part of the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#filtering_arrays)

Comment: Hi. I look for the answer to the same question. For the ones asking for data, here is a sample case:          WITH TEST_DATA AS (
SELECT 1001 as message_id, "Source 1" as message_type, ARRAY["Error type 1", "Error type 2"] as errors
UNION ALL
SELECT 1002 as message_id, "Source 1" as message_type, ARRAY["Error type 1", "Error type 3"] as errors
UNION ALL
SELECT 1003 as message_id,
"Source 2" as message_type, ARRAY["Error type 2"] as errors )
SELECT message_type, ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(errors) errors 
FROM TEST_DATA
GROUP BY message_type

Comment: So, in the example of this previous comment, ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(errors) works but ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(DISTINCT errors) does not work

Answer (score 1):

Indeed ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(DISTINCT ) does not work. Yet, in my case the following works fine. Would that be helpful for you too?

```
WITH
  TEST_DATA AS (
    SELECT 1001 AS message_id, "Source 1" AS message_type, ARRAY["Error type 1", "Error type 2"] AS errors
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1002 AS message_id, "Source 1" AS message_type, ARRAY["Error type 1", "Error type 3"] AS errors
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1003 AS message_id, "Source 2" AS message_type, ARRAY["Error type 2"] AS errors )
  , 
  CONSOLIDATED AS (
    SELECT message_type, ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(errors) errors FROM  TEST_DATA GROUP BY message_type
  )
SELECT message_type, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT errors) errors
  FROM CONSOLIDATED, UNNEST(errors) errors
GROUP BY message_type
```

After the comment of [deepak-lewis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8151366/deepak-lewis) I come up with a second option:

```
WITH
  TEST_DATA AS (
    SELECT 1001 AS message_id, "Source 1" AS message_type, ARRAY["Error type 1", "Error type 2"] AS errors
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1002 AS message_id, "Source 1" AS message_type, ARRAY["Error type 1", "Error type 3"] AS errors
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1003 AS message_id, "Source 2" AS message_type, ARRAY["Error type 2"] AS errors )
  , 
  UNNESTED AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT message_type, errors 
    FROM TEST_DATA, UNNEST(errors) errors
  )
SELECT message_type, ARRAY_AGG(errors)
  FROM UNNESTED
GROUP BY message_type
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that for large datasets, the `ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(errors)` part 

will fail with this error:
`Cannot query rows larger than 100MB limit.`